# svnadmin: SQLite is required to be compiled and run in thread-safe mode

Tags: svn, sqlite

I am getting this error when trying to use svn on my shared hosting account [hostmonster]

svnadmin: SQLite is required to be compiled and run in thread-safe mode

My SQLite is in /usr/bin 
How can i configured svn with SQLite

Answer (score 1):

This tells you that subversion was compiled with invalid settings. You should recompile Subversion with the right settings (or ask the hoster to do just that).

You might be able to workaround this issue by using --pre-1.6-compatible if this error is specific for 'svn create', but I haven't tried this. (And my guess is that it won't work, but trying doesn't hurt)